# Need to create a countdown after a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I'm very new to coding. I am working on a simple game, when you die it shows something like "Thanks for playing, your score is *_*." On the next line is a button that says "Play Again." I made the button reset the game and automatically start a new one. It would be nice if I could have some help adding a countdown to the button. After it's pressed I would like a 3, 2, 1 to show on the screen and THEN it starts the game.

```
`{
var msg_score = document.getElementById("msg");
msg_score.innerHTML = "Thanks for playing!<br /> Your Score : <b>"+score+"</b><br /><br /><input type='button' value='Play Again' onclick='window.location.reload();' />";
document.getElementById("playArea").style.display = 'none';
window.clearInterval(interval);
}`
```

Comment: paste the code here, please. Questions here can't be dependent on external resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function that creates the requested count down.

```
function count_down(seconds) {
    var msg_score = document.getElementById("msg");
    if(seconds <= 0) {
        window.location.reload();
        return;
    }
    msg_score.innerHTML = msg_score.innerHTML + "<br/>" + seconds;
    seconds--;
    setTimeout(count_down(seconds), 1000);
}
```

and change `onclick='window.location.reload();'` to `count_down(3);`

Answer (score 0):

What u need is a delay function..

This is an example here the function will print another string after 2 seconds..

I don't know what exactly u want to print or which function you want to execute so I have generalized the code for understanding.. You can call a function or print according to your program needs..

```
    function callback(a){
           return function(){
        alert("Hello " + a);
            }
    }

   var a = "world";
   setTimeout(callback(a), 2000);
   a = "Stack Overflow";
```

EDIT: also that setTimeout function takes in time in milliseconds.. So 2000 ms = 2 sec